# How can I prevent semaphore lockup when thread is terminated with bus error

Tags: linux-kernel, semaphore, linux-device-driver

I am developing a Linux device driver running on an embedded CPU. This device driver control some external hardware. The external hardware has it's own DDR controler and external DDR. The hardware's DDR is visible on the embedded CPU via a movable memory window (so I have paged access to the external DDR from the Linux driver). I'm using Linux kernel version 2.6.33.

My driver uses sysfs to allow control of the external hardware from userspace. As an example, the external hardware generates a heartbeat counter which increments a specific address in external DDR. The driver reads this to detect if the external hardware is still running.

If the external DDR is not working correctly then an access to the external DDR produces a bus error on the embedded CPU. To protect against simultaneous multi-thread access, the driver uses a semaphore.

Now to the problem. If a thread grabs the semaphore, then terminates with a bus error, the semaphore is still locked. All subsequent calls to grab the semaphore block indefinatly. What techniques can I use to avoid this hanging the driver forever?

An example sysfs function (simplified):

```
static ssize_t running_attr_show(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, char *buffer)
{
    struct my_device * const my_dev = container_of(dev, struct my_device, dev);
    int ret;

    if(down_interruptible(&my_dev->sem))
    {
        ret = -ERESTARTSYS;
    }
    else
    {
        u32 heartbeat;
        int running;

        // Following line could cause bus error
        heartbeat = mwindow_get_reg(&my_dev->mwindow, HEARTBEAT_COUNTER_ADDR);

        running = (heartbeat != my_dev->last_heartbeat) ? 1 : 0;
        my_dev->last_heartbeat = heartbeat;

        ret = sprintf(buffer, "%d\n", result);

        /* unlock */
        up(&my_dev->sem);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to modify `mwindow_get_reg()` and possibly the architecture fault handler that's invoked on a bus error so that `mwindow_get_reg()` can return an error, rather than terminating the process.

You can then handle that error gracefully, by releasing the semaphore and returning an error to userspace.

Comment: thanks. Certainly something to consider. Do you have any suggestions for how the exception handler can know that the cause of the bus error was a call from mwindow_get_reg? We have some code already that does some probing, which relies on a static variable set before the access, detected during the fault so that another static can be set, then checked after the access. Interrupts are disabled during the whole process. This does not seem very elegant and would mean interrupts were disabled for long periods when copying large amounts of firmware to the target DDR via the memory window.

Comment: @qbert220: Take a look at your architecture's implementation of `copy_from_user()` - that function necessarily sets things up so that unrecoverable page faults will return `EFAULT` to the caller rather than cause a panic (you'll also have to see how the page fault handler does its part of the job).

Comment: This is a fairly simple architecture. The copy_to_user implementation calls access_ok (which checks the address is in the expected range) and returns -EFAULT if this returns false. In all other cases it calls memcpy and returns the number of bytes that were requested to be copied (the memcpy return value is ignored).

Comment: @qbert220: `access_ok()` typically just checks if a copy will be *definitely* bad (eg out of the userspace address range) - the copy can still fault after `access_ok()` returns true.  For example, in the x86 architecture, exception table entries are added describing the particular `%eip` values pointing to instructions that are allowed to fault, along with the address to continue after the fault.  See [`fixup_exception()`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.38/arch/x86/mm/extable.c#L6) in `linux/arch/x86/mm/extable.c` for example.  What architecture are you writing for?

Comment: thanks - I've worked it out now and I've posted by actual implementation as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @caf, here is the solution I've implemented.

I've converted part of mwindow_get_reg to assembly. For the possible faulting read I've added an entry into the ex_table section with the faulting address and fixup address. This causes the exception handler to jump to the fixup code instead of terminating the thread if an exception occurs at this address. The fixup assembler sets a 'faulted' flag, which I can then test for in my c code:

```
unsigned long ret = 0;
int faulted;

asm volatile(
        "  1:      lwi     %0, %2, 0;         "     // ret = *window_addr
        "  2:      addik   %1, r0, 0;         "     // faulted = 0
        "  3:                                 "
        "          .section .fixup, \"ax\";   "     // fixup code executed if exception occurs
        "  4:      brid    3b;                "     // jump to next line of c code
        "          addik   %1, r0, 1;         "     // faulted = 1 (in delay slot)
        "          .previous;                 "
        "          .section __ex_table,\"a\"; "
        "          .word   1b,4b;             "     // ex_table entry. Gives fault address and jump address if fault occurs
        "          .previous;                 "
           : "=r" (ret), "=r" (faulted)             // output registers
           : "r" (window_addr)                      // input registers
);

if (faulted)
{
    printk(KERN_ERROR "%s: %s: FAULTED!", MODNAME, __FUNCTION__);
    ret = 0xdeadbeef;
}
```

I also had to modify my DBUS exception handler by adding the following:

```
const struct exception_table_entry *fixup;
fixup = search_exception_tables(regs->pc);
if (fixup) {
    printk(KERN_ERROR "DBUS exception: calling fixup\n");
    regs->pc = fixup->fixup;
    return;
}
```